# Does call to taskSpawn() blocks until the spawned task completes

Tags: vxworks

I am rather new to vxworks(I am using version 6.7),  and I find that when I spawn a child task,  the parent seems to block till the child task completes. Perhaps,  my understanding is not correct,  and there is some parameter to be set in taskSpawn(),  telling it not to block till the code task had completed. 
Is there such a parameter or is there some other mechanism to bit make the parent task wait for completion of the child?

Comment: taskSpawn doesn't wait for the task to complete. But if your new task has a higher priority than the one that spawned it, it's going to run until it gives up the CPU(by e.g. exiting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check priorities for your tasks. The default VxWorks scheduler is priority-based preemptive scheduling.